# Table of contents for an ebook

Tags: tables, ux-field, hierarchy, best-practice

I am working on Ebook and want to display the table of contents of the eBook. It will have units, chapters in the unit, topics in each chapter.

Any best practices to display the Table of contents for an easy feel to the students? Ideally the Table of contents will be on each page on the left hand side. I am thinking of having an Expand option prefixing each unit, chapter and topic. If user would like to expand, then it can be expanded. Else it will show short content i.e; for only units. If anyone has good ideas it really helps.

Comment: Why do you want the index to always be visible?

Comment: Its a place holder by default. And the ebook occupies the rest of the page. It wont be visible. The TOC window is minimised. When student want to go to any other topic, he can slide the TOC and just click on the topic, instead of escaping from the ebook to find the topic from the index

Answer (score 1):

Indentations in your TOC will make it much easier to distinguish chapters, units, and topics (see screenshot). This can be combined with your idea of collapsible chapters/units/etc. so that when they are expanded, it is still easy to distinguish which is which.

[image]